# Javamail no newline on attachment

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am sending a text attachment using JavaMail API and the attachment 
is encoded correctly. However, it seems there are no newlines in the 
attachment display as the lines are wrapped incorrectly. I have 
even tried `rt` instead of `rb`.

```
is = (new ZFile(inFileName, "rb")).getInputStream();
InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
byte[] bytearray = IOUtils.toByteArray(rdr);
DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytearray, "application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Is the problem with the MIME content of the message?  Is the problem with displaying the content after you read it?  Is the problem with reading the data into the byte array?  Is that ZFile from z/OS?  It says you need to [open the file in text/stream mode, not binary](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSYKE2_6.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.60.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/ZFile.html#getInputStream%28%29), to use the getInputStream method.  (I'm just reading their docs, I know nothing about this.)

Comment: Its is a z/OS file. The attachment is arabic data and the data displays fine in Notepad when I download it from the mail(except that it is flipped, but that is a different issue). However it seems there are no newlines so the data is  wrapped.  I have been reading about   system.getproperty( line.separator ), don't know if this might help, will try.

Comment: How is the original data stored?  Is it stored as text with newlines?  Or is it stored as records?  Do you see the newlines in the byte array you're creating?  If not, the problem is in how you're reading the file, not in how you're sending it in email.

Comment: Does the "b" in "rb" mean "binary"?  If you just use "r" does it work?

Comment: I see the issue now. The data  has X'0A' but Notepad needs X'0D0A' CRLF. In Wordpad the data looks fine. I am now trying to change the 0A to 0D0A using the System.getProperty but the value is not being set at all.